# Linq to SQL - Add Intellisense to Generated Classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-sql

Is there any method to add intellisense to designer-generated classes and properties in LINQ to SQL? I Want to add this comments to show documentation what class or property mean in project.

I have created New LINQ to SQL Classes in Visual Studio and mapped by Server Explorer a sample table. If i do query such as:

```
var items = from s in db.SampleTable select s;
```

When I type db + dot = nothing useful shows...

The same problem occurs when I do code like this:

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.ID);
}
```

When I type item + dot = also nothing useful shows...

Is there any method to add Intellisense to to this ? We could add Comments/XML to *.designer.cs class - but if I regenerate code - It will clear all comments...

Any help for making it work would be very appreciated.

**EDIT**: Sorry, but to be more specific - I have in mind missing XML documentation...

Comment: Does your code compile? All generated stuff should be known to IntelliSense.

Comment: yes, it compiles - StriplingWarrior rightly pointed that - I mean I can't add XML documentation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add XML Comments to class properties generated by the LINQ to SQL designer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37519/add-xml-comments-to-class-properties-generated-by-the-linq-to-sql-designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes all have intellisense: that's what makes the `SampleTable` show up in a list when you type `db.`.

What you're asking about is XML documentation. If you are using an EDMX to generate the entity context, you should be able to right-click an Entity type or Property, go to Properties, and there will be a field where you can enter descriptive information which will cause XML comments to be generated on the class or property.

#### Edit

Oh, right, LINQ to SQL. Try following the instructions [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/08/18/using-linq-to-sql-xml-mapping-files-step-by-step.aspx) to create a separate XML comments mapping file.

Comment: I am using dbml (Linq to SQL classes item).

Comment: @Redzio: Okay, sorry I didn't pay close enough attention. See my update.